# Why is compiler generating 4-byte load instead of 1-byte load where the wider load may access unmapped data?

Tags: c, compiler-optimization

I have a byte buffer filled with variable-length records, whose length is determined by the first byte of the record. A reduced version of a C function to read a single record

```
void mach_parse_compressed(unsigned char* ptr, unsigned long int* val)
{
    if (ptr[0] < 0xC0U) {
        *val = ptr[0] + ptr[1];
        return;
    }

  *val = ((unsigned long int)(ptr[0]) << 24)
      | ((unsigned long int)(ptr[1]) << 16)
      | ((unsigned long int)(ptr[2]) << 8)
      | ptr[3];
}
```

generates assembly (GCC 5.4 -O2 -fPIC on x86_64) that loads four bytes at ptr first, compares the first byte with 0xC0, and then processes either two, either four bytes. The undefined bytes are thrown away correctly, but why does compiler think that it's safe to load four bytes in the first place? Since there is no e.g. alignment requirement for ptr, it may point to the last two bytes of a memory page that is next to an unmapped one for all we know, resulting in a crash.

Both -fPIC and -O2 or higher are required to reproduce.

Am I missing something here? Is compiler correct in doing this and how do I workaround this?

I can get the above show Valgrind/AddressSanitiser errors or a crash with mmap/mprotect:

```
//#define HEAP
#define MMAP
#ifdef MMAP
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#elif HEAP
#include <stdlib.h>
#endif

void
mach_parse_compressed(unsigned char* ptr, unsigned long int* val)
{
    if (ptr[0] < 0xC0U) {
        *val = ptr[0] + ptr[1];
        return;
    }

    *val = ((unsigned long int)(ptr[0]) << 24)
        | ((unsigned long int)(ptr[1]) << 16)
        | ((unsigned long int)(ptr[2]) << 8)
        | ptr[3];
}

int main(void)
{
    unsigned long int val;
#ifdef MMAP
    int error;
    long page_size = sysconf(_SC_PAGESIZE);
    unsigned char *buf = mmap(NULL, page_size * 2, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,
                              MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);
    unsigned char *ptr = buf + page_size - 2;
    if (buf == MAP_FAILED)
    {
        perror("mmap");
        return 1;
    }
    error = mprotect(buf + page_size, page_size, PROT_NONE);
    if (error != 0)
    {
        perror("mprotect");
        return 2;
    }
    *ptr = 0xBF;
    *(ptr + 1) = 0x10;
    mach_parse_compressed(ptr, &val);
#elif HEAP
    unsigned char *buf = malloc(16384);
    unsigned char *ptr = buf + 16382;
    buf[16382] = 0xBF;
    buf[16383] = 0x10;
#else
    unsigned char buf[2];
    unsigned char *ptr = buf;
    buf[0] = 0xBF;
    buf[1] = 0x10;
#endif
    mach_parse_compressed(ptr, &val);
}
```

MMAP version:

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

With Valgrind:

```
==3540== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==3540==  Bad permissions for mapped region at address 0x4029000
==3540==    at 0x400740: mach_parse_compressed (in /home/laurynas/gcc-too-wide-load/gcc-too-wide-load)
==3540==    by 0x40060A: main (in /home/laurynas/gcc-too-wide-load/gcc-too-wide-load)
```

With ASan:

```
ASAN:SIGSEGV
=================================================================
==3548==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: SEGV on unknown address 0x7f8f4dc25000 (pc 0x000000400d8a bp 0x0fff884e56c6 sp 0x7ffc4272b620 T0)
    #0 0x400d89 in mach_parse_compressed (/home/laurynas/gcc-too-wide-load/gcc-too-wide-load+0x400d89)
    #1 0x400b92 in main (/home/laurynas/gcc-too-wide-load/gcc-too-wide-load+0x400b92)
    #2 0x7f8f4c72082f in __libc_start_main (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x2082f)
    #3 0x400c58 in _start (/home/laurynas/gcc-too-wide-load/gcc-too-wide-load+0x400c58)

AddressSanitizer can not provide additional info.
SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: SEGV ??:0 mach_parse_compressed
```

HEAP version with Valgrind:

```
==30498== Invalid read of size 4
==30498==    at 0x400603: mach_parse_compressed (mach0data_reduced.c:9)
==30498==    by 0x4004DE: main (mach0data_reduced.c:34)
==30498==  Address 0x520703e is 16,382 bytes inside a block of size 16,384 alloc'd
==30498==    at 0x4C2DB8F: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:299)
==30498==    by 0x4004C0: main (mach0data_reduced.c:24)
```

Stack version with ASan:

```
==30528==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: stack-buffer-overflow on address
0x7ffd50000440 at pc 0x000000400b63 bp 0x7ffd500003c0 sp
0x7ffd500003b0
READ of size 4 at 0x7ffd50000440 thread T0
    #0 0x400b62 in mach_parse_compressed
CMakeFiles/innobase.dir/mach/mach0data_reduced.c:15
    #1 0x40087e in main CMakeFiles/innobase.dir/mach/mach0data_reduced.c:34
    #2 0x7f3be2ce282f in __libc_start_main
(/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x2082f)
    #3 0x400948 in _start
(/home/laurynas/obj-percona-5.5-release/storage/innobase/CMakeFiles/innobase.dir/mach/mach0data_test+0x400948)
```

Thanks

**EDIT:** added MMAP version that actually crashes, clarified compiler options

**EDIT 2:** reported it as https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=77673. For workaround, inserting a compiler memory barrier `asm volatile("": : :"memory");` after the `if` statement resolves the issue. Thanks everyone!

Comment: Sounds like a compiler bug. You might want to file a bug report.

Comment: Possible, but wanted to check with language lawyers / compiler experts here first, too often an apparent compiler bug is user error

Comment: The compiler might have knowledge that this 4-byte load could never cause a crash on the target architecture (valgrind report notwithstanding). If you could produce an example that actually does crash then it would strengthen the case for a compiler bug.

Comment: Gcc is clearly cheating.  It knows that alignment is not a problem (because this is the x86).  It's less clear that it knows anything about `malloc`.  To get it to really break, try using `mmap` and `mprotect` to get your buffer into a page followed by an unreadable page.  If gcc still does the four-byte load, it will cross into the unreadable page and you should get a runtime fault and hence have a nice bug-demo.

Comment: The code is generated with the function in its separate compilation unit - GCC may not assume anything about the origin or value of the pointer. I will try to create an actual crashing example.

Comment: @M.M, I have added a mmap/mprotect version that actually crashes

Comment: @torek, I have used your mmap/mprotect suggestion

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gcc-5/+bug/1612143

Comment: I don't think memory maps can end in "odd" places. The compiler is cheating. I doubt that this will cause problems in C anyway.

Comment: Interesting question.  I just tried it with the VS 2015 compiler with max optimization and it made no assumption about the availability of the [2] and [3] entries.  Clearly, if it WERE okay to do so, a single 32 bit memory access would be more efficient, but it sure looks like a case of overzealous optimization.  I wonder if it would have done the same if the function were better structured (e.g., if / else).

Comment: @NoelC, the original function is if / else if ... / else: https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/blob/5.5/storage/innobase/mach/mach0data.c#L38

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Congratulations! You found a genuine compiler bug!

You can use http://gcc.godbolt.org to explore assembly output from different compilers and options.

With gcc version 6.2 for x86 64-bit linux, using `gcc -fPIC -O2`, your function does compile to **incorrect** code:

```
mach_parse_compressed(unsigned char*, unsigned long*):
    movzbl  (%rdi), %edx
    movl    (%rdi), %eax   ; potentially incorrect load of 4 bytes
    bswap   %eax
    cmpb    $-65, %dl
    jbe     .L5
    movl    %eax, %eax
    movq    %rax, (%rsi)
    ret
.L5:
    movzbl  1(%rdi), %eax
    addl    %eax, %edx
    movslq  %edx, %rdx
    movq    %rdx, (%rsi)
    ret
```

You correctly diagnosed the problem and the `mmap` example provides a good regression test. `gcc` is trying too hard to optimize this function and the resulting code is definitely incorrect: reading 4 bytes from an unaligned address is OK for most X86 operating environments, but reading past the end of an array is not.

The compiler could assume that reads past the end of an array are OK if they do not cross a 32 bit or even 64 bit boundary, but this assumption is incorrect for your example.  You might be able to get a crash for a block allocated with `malloc` if you make it large enough. `malloc` uses `mmap` for very large blocks (>= 128KB by default IRCC).

Note that this **bug** was introduced with version 5.1 of the compiler.

`clang` on the other hand does not have this problem, but the code seems less efficient in the general case:

```
#    @mach_parse_compressed(unsigned char*, unsigned long*)
mach_parse_compressed(unsigned char*, unsigned long*):         
    movzbl  (%rdi), %ecx
    cmpq    $191, %rcx
    movzbl  1(%rdi), %eax
    ja      .LBB0_2
    addq    %rcx, %rax
    movq    %rax, (%rsi)
    retq
.LBB0_2:
    shlq    $24, %rcx
    shlq    $16, %rax
    orq     %rcx, %rax
    movzbl  2(%rdi), %ecx
    shlq    $8, %rcx
    orq     %rax, %rcx
    movzbl  3(%rdi), %eax
    orq     %rcx, %rax
    movq    %rax, (%rsi)
    retq
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems compiler optimize access to ptr. It is possible to disable optimization to access to ptr just adding keyword volatile. In this case there is no crash for MMAP variant.

```
//#define HEAP
#define MMAP
#ifdef MMAP
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#elif HEAP
#include <stdlib.h>
#endif

void
mach_parse_compressed(volatile unsigned char* ptr, unsigned long int* val)
{
    if (ptr[0] < 0xC0U) {
        *val = ptr[0] + ptr[1];
        return;
    }

    *val = ((unsigned long int)(ptr[0]) << 24)
        | ((unsigned long int)(ptr[1]) << 16)
        | ((unsigned long int)(ptr[2]) << 8)
        | ptr[3];
}

int main(void)
{
    unsigned long int val;
#ifdef MMAP
    int error;
    long page_size = sysconf(_SC_PAGESIZE);
    unsigned char *buf = (unsigned char *) mmap(NULL, page_size * 2, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,
                              MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);
    unsigned char *ptr = buf + page_size - 2;
    if (buf == MAP_FAILED)
    {
        perror("mmap");
        return 1;
    }
    error = mprotect(buf + page_size, page_size, PROT_NONE);
    if (error != 0)
    {
        perror("mprotect");
        return 2;
    }
    *ptr = 0xBF;
    *(ptr + 1) = 0x10;
    mach_parse_compressed(ptr, &val);
#elif HEAP
    unsigned char *buf = malloc(16384);
    unsigned char *ptr = buf + 16382;
    buf[16382] = 0xBF;
    buf[16383] = 0x10;
#else
    unsigned char buf[2];
    unsigned char *ptr = buf;
    buf[0] = 0xBF;
    buf[1] = 0x10;
#endif
    mach_parse_compressed(ptr, &val);
}
```

Comment: I wonder (will try later) if I can insert a memory barrier instead of heavy volatile-hammer for a workaround

Comment: Yep, a "asm volatile("": : :"memory");" after the if statement is a work around, and does not pessimize code.

Answer (score 1):

On some architectures (e.g. STM32), a 4-byte load/store operation is applied on the 4-byte segment in which the operand is "located".

For example, a 4-byte load from address 0x80000003 will be applied on 0x80000000.

In addition to that, the memory bus maps an address space which starts at a 4-byte aligned address and contains an integer number of 4-byte segments.

For example, the address space starts at 0 (inclusive) and ends at 0x80000000 (exclusive).

Now, suppose that we take such architecture, and configure the bus to allow read (load) on the entire address space.

Subsequently, a 4-byte load operation will be completed successfully (without causing a bus fault) anywhere within the given address space.

---

Having said that, this is not the case on x86/x64 as far as I'm aware of...